# Convert fetchXML to sql temp table

Tags: sql, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, reporting-services, fetchxml

We are about to convert or CRM report to CRM online report using fetchXML
The report is based on CRM database and my custom database
Is it possible convert fetchXML result into a temp table so i can join the temp table with other queries. 
thanks for all the help

Comment: So, you're using Dynamics CRM (2011?) online, and you want to somehow natively access Microsoft's SQL Server instance that houses your data and join to your organization's database? If so, I don't think this is happening anytime soon.

Comment: Yea basically my report based on local SQL Server data and dynamics CRM 2011 online data.  So i will have to get both data and generate a report with BIDs and display the report in the reporting server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your best bet will be to create a [CLR stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx) that retrieves the data via [fetchxml](/questions/tagged/fetchxml) or [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) (or [query-expressions](/questions/tagged/query-expressions)) then stores it in a temp table (or any other table), which you'd then be able to join to your own tables. The obvious drawback is that you have to pull in *all* the data from your CRM data source before you can filter it via a join, but you might be able to be creative about this to prefilter your CRM data to just the data that's pertinent to your actual query.

There's at least [one post on the MSDN Forums](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/crmdevelopment/thread/c7274112-2161-4ce6-b546-dd25b6cc7625) that addresses fairly well the process of registering the requisite CRM assemblies to your database fairly well, so that should help to give you a fair head start.